# Change constraints that are set on the parent view from within the child view

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am having the following problem over and over again and I am looking for a clean solution to do this.

I have multiple views: a parent view (my rootView, controlled by my basic UIViewController) and a descendant view (a UICollectionViewCell in a UICollectionView which is a subview of my rootView).

The size of the UICollectionView is relative to the size of my rootView: in the UIViewController of the rootView, where I created the UICollectionView, I also created constraints (between the rootView and the UICollectionView) and added them to the rootView.

**When a button is tapped in the UICollectionViewCell I want to change the size of the UICollectionView. Therefore I need to alter the constraints that are set on my rootView.**

I have been told that accessing the constraints of the rootView via a downcast of the UIViewController and changing them this way is dirty, because having a view talk back to its (parent)controller is wrong.

How am I supposed to act in such a situation? How can I make the controller react to the view without the view talking to the controller? A point in the right direction would be great!

Comment: You said "I have multiple views: a parent view and a child view that is the parent view‘s subview. " Do you mean that you have a child view **controller** who's view is the parent view **controller's** subview? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I believe that’s what I meant, yes. To be specific I am talking about a collectionViewController, who's view is placed in my rootView. (The button is in my collectionViewCell, so there are even three views nested, but I guess if I understood the principle once I will be able to transfer it to this specific situation.)

Comment: The term view and view controller are **not** interchangeable. A `UIView` is a subclass of UIView, and displays content on the screen and/or gathers information from a user. A `UIViewController` is a controller object that manages a set of views. When asking questions, make sure to never mix your terms.

Comment: A `UICollectionView`? That's not a view controller, it's view.  There is also a class `UICollectionViewController`, which is designed to manage a collection view, although I don't know that I've ever used one of those. Please use the full names of the classes you are talking about so we can tell **EXACTLY** what you mean. Details matter when asking for help.

Comment: I’m sorry for not being clear, I am not experienced with those terms yet. I tried to add a description that is as clear as possible, and I will clear up my initial question later. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I'll look at your question again later, when you go back and edit your post to use use the term UIView or UIViewController in each instance. Otherwise it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I edit my post and tried to be as clear with the terms as possible. Again, thanks for taking time – I am very insecure with this and appreciate your help and criticism!

Answer (score 0):

After your edits, it sounds like you only have one view controller in play here. In that case, life is good. The logic to manipulate the constraints that control your collection view belongs in the view controller.

You want to pass the button taps to your view controller, and have it handle resizing the collection view.

How are you handling button taps?

Comment: Right now, in my UICollectionViewCell init function I write `button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTap:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` and I have a function called buttonTap in that very same Class.

Comment: I am now using an NSNotification and its working great – I couldn’t figure out how to use a protocol – to be specific where to tell the Cell it’s delegate

Comment: Make the addTarget call in your viewController's cellForItemAtIndexPath method. Then you don't need to worry about delegates.